# Rewrite routes from hosting to cloud functions from other regions than us-central1

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have a http triggered cloud function deployed in the *europe-west1* region and a web app hosted with firebase hosting.
I have also setup a rewrite to that http function in my *firebase.json* file.

I have noticed that the rewrite only works with *us-central1* functions.

**Is there a way to make the rewrite work with *europe-west1* functions?**

Comment: I have noticed the same problem. Could you figure it out in the meantime?

Comment: Now that there is official support for other regions it states in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions) that "**_If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for hosting, you must use us-central1_**". So i think we have to wait and see if they will change that.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I must be blind ;)

Comment: That sounds like an answer @dergoegge! :)

Answer (score 6):

Now that there is official support for other regions it states in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions) that "***If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for hosting, you must use us-central1***". So i think we have to wait and see if they will change that.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021, Hosting rewrites to functions work for us-central1 region only

[image: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-entral1 only]

Answer (score 2):

Since August 2022 it is now possible to configure Firebase Hosting routes to rewrite to Cloud Functions in a specific region.

See this [update in the public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175766484?pli=1), and the documentation on [direction HTTPS requests to your function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function) where you can now specify a region too. The region is optional and if `region` is omitted from the `hosting` config, the Firebase CLI will attempt to automatically detect the region from the function's source code.

Comment: It is worth noting: This feature will only work with the updated Firebase CLI as several deployment changes were made. Older CLI versions will not work. I had to update from 9.10.0