# Firebase call Google Cloud function issue - two functions with the same name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've got two Google Cloud functions with the same name but in two different regions.

How do I specify which function should be called (as there are two of them with the same name)?

My firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/test",
        "function": "paaspiutil"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can current only deploy functions in us-central1 if you want to link it to hosting [as referenced in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178657/rewrite-routes-from-hosting-to-cloud-functions-from-other-regions-than-us-centra#comment90299996_51178657) and [heres the links to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions)